# Getting SynchronousOnlyOperation while creating an object in async function in django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-asyncio

While running this:

```
async def func():
    print("This is async function")
    Program.objects.create(name="New Program")


asyncio.run(func())
```

Getting this:

`Error : SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.`

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/async/#async-safety)

Answer (score 0):

try this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/async/#queries-the-orm

if you use django < 4:

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
def func():
    print("This is async function")
    Program.objects.create(name="New Program")


await sync_to_async(func)()
```

if you use django > 3.2:

```
def func():
        print("This is async function")
        await Program.objects.acreate(name="New Program")
    
    
    asyncio.run(func())
```